# Where do I get Commission and SEC Fee data for an Investment Transaction?

Tags: yodlee

The developer documentation on the fields available for an [Investment Transaction](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model/Investment_Transaction) (see linked page) indicates that **Commission** and **SEC Fee** data are *Often* available for investment transactions, but these fields didn't appear to be available in the data returned by [executeUserSearchRequest](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/executeUserSearchRequest) for my sample accounts. How do I request data for these fields?

Here's what my current request looks like:

```
    /jsonsdk/TransactionSearchService/executeUserSearchRequest
        ?transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.fromDate=09-03-2014
        &transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.toDate=09-10-2014
        &transactionSearchRequest.containerType=All
        &transactionSearchRequest.lowerFetchLimit=1
        &transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientName=DataSearchService
        &transactionSearchRequest.higherFetchLimit=1000
        &transactionSearchRequest.ignoreUserInput=True
        &transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientId=1
        &transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.startNumber=1
        &transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.endNumber=100
        &transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.transactionSplitType=ALL_TRANSACTION
        &transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.itemAccountId.identifier=XXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These fields are currently not available via the executeUserSearchRequest API. We will be working on to fix the API to return these fields.